# remove file name from url in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having trouble with my url appending on 'filename.php' when certain page gets loaded.

After navigating to for example:

domain.com/page1

If I try to navigate to page2 I would expect this result

domain.com/page2
but instead I get
dmomain.com/page1/page2

This problem only occurs when navigating to page1, if I navigate to any other page and series of pages, this appedning of pages on the url does not occur.

I am sure its my htaccess and have a decent idea where the problem is in it, just not sure how to setup my condition to stop this problem. Here is my htaccess

```
   RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page1/([^\.]+)
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain.com)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page1/([^\.]+)
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.php/$2 [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page1/([^\.]+) // checks if request_uri matches 'page1/[SOME_DIR]'
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/page1/([^\.]+)\.(php) // trying to check if [SOME_DIR] does not have '.php' on the end
    // this should resolve the 'page1/page2' issue, since I dont want a rewrite to occur when [SOME_DIR] has '.php'
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ $1.php/$2 [NC,L]
```

I have thought about creating a condition where this last rewrite wont occur when the {REQUEST_URI} contains 'page2' or 'page3'. This opens up a problem of having to enter a new page in htaccess for each different link. Dont like that at all.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what your current rules are doing. Are you trying to hide `.php` extension by these rules?

Comment: Thats one issue which is partially resolved, but the larger issue is that once navigating to page1, it stays in the url no matter where I navigate after that. I believe the last rewrite rule is causing it, just not sure what condition I need to apply to resolve this appending problem